# Method to check if point is inside the rect? (moving objects in boundary)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, geometry

What I want to do is to move object, box for example on top of another box but not to go over the boundaries. Think moving picture on the wall. So if I am dragging smaller object when I get to the edge object stops moving in that direction but in others it can move (for example can't go over left edge but can move up and down). I am trying to figure out how to determine if object edge, point on the object edge or center point with half of the size of the object in that axis is inside the rect, not over the boundary of the object in that axis.

The problem here that smaller object has a little offset from the bigger one, they are not on the same plane. Another problem is that planes are not aligned with world axis and the same method should work on other planes as well like the plane at some angles with points R2,R5,R6,R4

I have something already that is working for some cases but not for all, it's more complicated that I want it to be, there might be a lot easier solution so I am looking for advice here.

I am using a lot of points, plane, projecting etc... but there should be something simplier. Maybe I am overengineering here :)

[image]

EDIT:

i am actually using box collider bounds but using vertices that are faced forward of the bigger object (wall) and the same for smaller object (painting), just the ones that are facing -forward direction. so basically i am not dealing with rects. so basically the question would be how to check if any of the corners of the smaller object is inside the area that is made by corners of the bigger object.

- get the plane of the wall
- get points of the painting on the plane of the wall (because of the offset)
- somehow check if points are inside the area?

Comment: You could use [Rect.Contains](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect.Contains.html) for this. Define a rect using either R1, R4 or R2, R6 depending on the plane you are interested in.  Then call `Rect.Contains` for P1, P2, P3, P4 to see if any of the points are outside the large Rect.

Comment: but plane is not axis aligned, object can be rotated, I am using points that i get from a box collider of the objects

Comment: The drawing makes it look as if P and R are parallel.  If they are parallel you can ignore the offset.  If they are not parallel you can calculate P' which is the shadow cast onto R by P.  You can then use Rect.Contains with P' instead of P.

Comment: You can use [Collision.gameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-gameObject.html) to get the underlying objects that have the actual coordinates of P and R stored.

Comment: i have edited the original question

Comment: could you do a raycast from each corner of the small box in the direction of the wall? If any of those casts miss the walls collider then the smaller box has moved beyond the wall.

Comment: This sounds like you're just looking for how to perform collision detection, which is built in.

Answer (score 0):

So you're looking to determine whether a rectangular cuboid collides with a rectangle, correct?

Let's look at the simple case where your wall is perpendicular to the Y axis.

The only way to have a collision is if you have one or more corners of your painting on each side of the wall along the Y axis. Since all corners of the wall have the same value the Y axis, this means we can just use, for instance R1.

```
all_Py = Y value for all corners of the painting

collision = min(all_Py) < R1.y && max(all_Py) > R1.y
```

But as you said, the wall is not aligned with the world axis. So now we need to express the XYZ coordinates of the painting relative to the wall rather than in absolute terms. For that, we can apply a rotation to the coordinates of the corners of the wall and of the painting and use the simple collision check on the new coordinates. To apply a rotation, you simply multiply each vector by the proper rotation matrix, which we need to compute.

The rotation we want is the one that maps the normal vector of the wall to the Y-axis vector (0, 1, 0). The normal vector of the wall `v` is the cross product R1R3 x R3R4.

Once you have the two vectors, finding the rotation matrix is a fairly straightforward process for which I would really like some TeX markup, so instead of writing it here, I'll refer you to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/476311/681558) on math.stackexchange.com.